# Is it possible to add a dot below day on Android Material Datepicker?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android

[image: Calendar view]

I would like to add dots below specific dates, anyone knows if it's possible with the Material Components?

Answer (score 1):

It's a similar problem to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281693/how-to-highlight-dates-in-android-datepicker) - it does not seem to be currently supported by the MaterialDatePicker.

Feature request submitted [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2854), feel free to back it up.

**Update**

The feature has been implemented and it's now possible to add a dot below days in the Material DatePicker. The [material catalog](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/datepicker/CircleIndicatorDecorator.java) has a very clear example of such an implementation.

You need to extend the `DayViewDecorator` class and override one of the `getCompoundDrawable` methods to create the drawable (little circle under each desired date) - in this case it would be `getCompoundDrawableBottom`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32311286)