# How to add a "dot" below a DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker

I'm currently needing to show a little "dot" below some dates on MUIX DatePicker, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387252/is-it-possible-to-add-a-dot-below-day-on-android-material-datepicker).
May someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I am currently using this example: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#basic-usage also found something on Google, but outdated, and lost the link sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by manipulating ‍‍‍‍`renderDay` prop in `DatePicker` component.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        renderDay={(day, _value, DayComponentProps) => {
            return (
                <Badge
                    key={day.toString()}
                    overlap="circular"
                    badgeContent={
                        (!DayComponentProps.outsideCurrentMonth && [1, 3, 23].some(x => x === day.date())) ? "⚫" : undefined}
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'bottom',
                        horizontal: 'right'
                    }}
                    sx={{
                        '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
                            right: '50%'
                        }
                    }}
                >
                    <PickersDay {...DayComponentProps} />
                </Badge>
            );
        }}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Notice that, by means of :

```
anchorOrigin = {{
    vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'right'
}}
sx = {{
    '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
        right: '50%'
    }
}}
```

I placed the **dot** (bullet) at the center bottom of the days number.
Also this means :

```
badgeContent = {
    (!DayComponentProps.outsideCurrentMonth && [1, 3, 23].some(x => x === day.date())) ? "⚫" : undefined
}
```

If the days that are being shown in the calendar frame are neither related to the current month nor in `[1, 3, 23]`(Which naturally depends on your choice), do not show the **dot**.

Comment: Seems good, also, how would I do on multiple months?

Comment: @GeekCorner It depends on what days you want to mark. Are these days supposed to be fixed in all months or they have another pattern. Remember `day` object does not have just `date()` method!

Comment: days might be following a specific pattern per month in my case

Comment: Then you can do it like this : `[new Date('2022-10-21'),new Date('2022-10-28'),new Date('2022-11-05')].some(x => x.toDateString() === day.toDate().toDateString())) ? "⚫" : undefined}`. Checks the days you want in the whole year. Although there are other ways that depend on the conditions of your program. I hope it helps you. @GeekCorner